# Carrying out a Permutation test in R

Tags: r

I have a 200 × 102 data matrix called prostmat, it has measurements of gene activity in male cancer patients (cases, last 52 columns) and healthy men (controls, first 50 columns). I want to do a permutation test to compare the means in the case and control groups. I can sample the case/control labels randomly in each permutation, then calculate the absolute difference in means between the groups. I'll be taking B=1000. Here is my approach but I think there is something wrong here. Would appreciate help on this

```
 T=mean(prostmat[1:200,51:102])-mean(prostmat[1:200,1:50]) 
   B=1000
   n=200
   Ts <- rep(NaN, nrow=n, ncol=B)
   for (i in 1:n){
   for (b in 1:B){
     tmpx=sample(prostmat[i,51:102])
     tmpy=sample(prostmat[i,1:50])
     Ts[b]=(mean(tmpx)-mean(tmpy))
     p.val=sum(Ts<T)/B # HA: mean(x) < mean(y)
  }
  }
```

Comment: The best way to do this is to create a two column data with the first column being an indicator of control/treatment and the second column being the whole data. Should be a dataframe of dimensions 20400 by 2, then carry a permutaton test on this

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to create a two column data with the first column being an indicator of control/treatment and the second column being the whole data. Should be a dataframe of dimensions 20400 by 2, then carry a permutaton test on this:

```
#Create Data
a <- data.frame(group = 'control', gene = c(as.matrix(prostmat[, 1:50])))
b <- data.frame(group = 'treatment', gene = c(as.matrix(prostmat[, 51:102])))
data <- rbind(a, b)

# Carry the permutation:

mean_diff <- with(data, diff(tapply(gene, group, mean)))
# Same as with(data, mean(gene[group == 'treatment'] - mean(gene[group == 'control']))
    
B <- 1000
distribution <- numeric(B)
for(i in seq(B){
    distribution[i] <- with(data, diff(tapply(gene, sample(group), mean))) 
  }

# Calculate p_value

p_val <- mean(abs(distribution) >= abs(mean_diff)) # if the HA: mean(treatment) != mean(control)

p_val <- mean(distribution <= mean_diff) # # if the HA: mean(treatment) < mean(control)
```